# HLS m3u8 live streaming in React Native Expo Mobile App

Tags: react-native, video, stream, expo, http-live-streaming

I need to show live streaming video in Expo react native app. I tried expo-video but it only plays mp4 videos not live stream if i'm not wrong.  I don't want to eject from expo. Is there any expo library or any other way to play hls m2u8 or rtmp live streaming?

```
<Video
      source={{ uri: "http://videostream.teroair.com/hls/VIN1000201000001000/front/index.m3u8"}}
      rate={1.0}
      volume={1.0}
      isMuted={false}
      resizeMode="cover"
      shouldPlay = {true}
      isLooping = {false}
      useNativeControls = {true}
      usePoster = {true}
      onError = {this.handleVideoPlayBackError}
      style={styles.backgroundVideo}
/>
```

Comment: did you find a solution for your problem?

Comment: @Kob_24 No, I had to eject expo and convert the app into react native cli then I used Nodemedia client for streaming.